# ESP8266 problem with sending UDP to global network

Tags: arduino, network-programming, udp, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a problem with sending UDP packets using ESP8266 D1/D1 mini boards.
The thing is that when sending via local network I can see the packets arriving in Wireshark, but when I try to send globally (connecting the board to mobile hotspot), nothing arrives.
Ultimately I want to store the data in InfluxDB, but for now it does not even make it to the server.

Please take a look at the code i use, maybe someone can help.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WiFiUDP.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "my ssid"
#define WIFI_PASS "my password"

byte host[] = {server ip};
int port = 8888;

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
WiFiUDP udp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
  Serial.print("Connecting to WIFI");
  while (WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
  }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  Serial.println("Setup Complete.");
}

void loop() {

  udp.beginPacket(host,port);
  udp.write("exampleMessage");
  udp.endPacket();

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: firewall? you have a not standard port

Comment: As @Juraj said, firewall, router, routes, NAT, DNS resolution. The moment you step outside the local network, many things come into play. Check if you have Ping to server IP.